# Data Model Design and Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I am implementing a data model in `python` and would appreciate any feedback.

## Model

My data structure can be reduced to the following:

```
  {
        'source':{
            'name':None,
            'website':None
        },
        'car':
        [{
            'manufacturer':None,
            'model':None,
            'year':None,
            'horse_power':None,
            'top_speed':None,
            'unit_top_speed':'km/h',
            'zero_to_100':None,
            'unit_zero_to_100':'seconds'
        }]
    }
```

For my implementation, I created four classes:

- *Parent*: A class that contains methods used by all other classes.
- *Car* and *Source* (childen of *Parent*): Two intermediate classes modeling the fields `car;source`.
- *Child* (child of *Car* and *Source*): The end class for my model.

## Code

```
import warnings
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Parent Class
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Parent(object):
    """
    *Parent Class*

    Contains methods used by all other classes.
    """
    def check_validity(self, key, subset=None, warn=True):
        """
        Checks if key is a field of self.data.
        """
        if subset is None:
            if key in self.data.keys():
                return True
            else:
                if warn:
                    warnings.warn('Not allowed:\n\"{}\" is not a field of the given instance.'.format(key), UserWarning)
                return False
        else:
            if key in self.data[subset].keys():
                return True
            else:
                if warn:
                    warnings.warn('Not allowed:\n\"{}\" is not a field of the given instance.'.format(key), UserWarning)
                return False
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Sub-Classes
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Car(Parent):
    __template = {
        'manufacturer':None,
        'model':None,
        'year':None,
        'horse_power':None,
        'top_speed':None,
        'unit_top_speed':'km/h',
        'zero_to_100':None,
        'unit_zero_to_100':'seconds'
    }
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data = Car.__template.copy()
        for (k,v) in zip(kwargs.keys(), kwargs.values()):
            if self.check_validity(k):
                self.data[k] = v
class Source(Parent):
        __template = {
            'name':None,
            'website':None
        }
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.data = Source.__template.copy()
            for (k,v) in zip(kwargs.keys(), kwargs.values()):
                if self.check_validity(k):
                    self.data[k] = v
        def set_website(self, website):
            if not isinstance(website, str):
                raise Exception('Argument must be a string.')
            if self.__class__ is 'Source':
                if not self.check_validity(key='website', warn=True):
                    return
                self.data['website'] = website
                return
            else:
                if not self.check_validity(key='website', subset='source', warn=False):
                    return
                self.data['source']['website'] = website
                return
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Child Class
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Child(Car, Source):
    __template = {
        'source':{
            'name':None,
            'website':None
        },
        'car':
        [{
            'manufacturer':None,
            'model':None,
            'year':None,
            'horse_power':None,
            'top_speed':None,
            'unit_top_speed':'km/h',
            'zero_to_100':None,
            'unit_zero_to_100':'seconds'
        }]
    }
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data = Child.__template.copy()
        for (k,v) in zip(kwargs.keys(), kwargs.values()):
            if self.check_validity(k):
                self.data[k] = v
    def add_car(self, car):
        if not isinstance(car, Car):
            raise Exception('Argument must be of class Car.')
        self.data['car'].extend([car.data])
    def set_car(self, car):
        if not isinstance(car, Car):
            raise Exception('Argument must be of class Car.')
        self.data['car'] = ([car.data])
    def set_source(self, source):
        if not isinstance(source, Source):
            raise Exception('Argument must be of class Source.')
        self.data['source'] = source.data
```

## Notes

- The `__init__` methods all use `**kwargs` and a loop to be able to lazily pass fields and values when creating an instance, e.g.

  - `Car(model='M4', year=2015)` or
  - `Car(model='M4', top_speed = 250)`.
- The purpose of `check_validity` if twofold:

  1. It checks when defining an instance that all fields are valid, e.g. if one writes `Car(name='M4', top_speed = 250)`, then argument `name` is omitted (a warning is issued) as it is not a field of `Car.__template`.
  2. It is also used to deal with inheritance: The class *Source* has a `set_website` method. By inheritance, this method is passed to *Child*. However, a trivial `set_website` method that *only* overwrites would throw an error when used for *Child* instances as `Child.__template` does not have a field `website`, or even worse than an error it would create a brand new field. However, I would like to be able to use `Child.set_website` to overwrite `Child.__template['source']['website']`. In this example I could have just overwritten the method. But since I am dealing with this problem several times I would prefer not to have to overwrite. Here, `check_validity` is used as a safety measure to ensure that using the set-method *makes sense*.

Finally, to tackle to problem addressed in *2*, what I did when defining `set_website` was getting the class name `self.__class__`. That if the class is *Source* the method overwrites the field `website`, if not the method first subsets to the field `source` and inside that field it overwrites `website`.

---

Being a novice with that kind of tasks, I would appreciate any feedback, especially concerning